# select specific column from subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

My sample data with the Emp table

```
Emp

deptno eno
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       1
2       2
```

output:

```
deptno  eno
1        3
2        2
```

out of this i need to have only one column in final output only

```
deptno
1
2
```

I am trying to write

```
select deptno from emp where deptno in (select deptno,max(eno)
from emp
group by deptno);
```

It is throwing error

Comment: Why do you need those two departments? what's the logic or are you just selecting all the departments?

Comment: Your query makes no logical sense. It is the same as 

    select distinct deptno from dbo.emp order by deptno;

Why do you need the extra complication?

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking . . .

```
select distinct deptno
from emp;
```

Does that meet your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select deptno from emp where deptno in (
    select deptno from emp where eno in (
        select MAX(eno) from emp))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select deptno
from emp 
group by deptno
```